# Loop over files in folder and lines in file simultaneously.

Tags: bash

I have the following Bash file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# $1 is path of C executable
# $2 is path of folder with instances
# $3 is path of folder to save results

seed=333

# Write header to output file
echo "instance, cost, time" >> "$3/ACO/run.txt"

# Run ACO
for instance in "$2"/*
do
    y=${instance%.txt}
    output=$(eval "$1 --seed $seed --instance $instance --runtime 10 --aco --rep")

    filename=${y##*/}
    length=${#filename}
    first=$(echo ${filename:3:$length-4} | awk '{print toupper($0)}')
    second=${filename:$length-1:1}

    echo "$first.$second, $output" >> "$3/ACO/run.txt"
done
```

This Bash file runs an algorithm in C on each instance (a `.txt` file) located in the folder specified by the second argument (`$2`). This algorithm requires different command line arguments, as can be seen by the call to `eval`(e.g. `--seed` and `--instance`).

Now, my problem is this. I have another `.txt` file which specifies for each instance the value for the command line argument `--runtime`. The values in this file are in the same order as the instances in the instances folder.

So my question is, how can I loop simultaneously over the instances in the instance folder and over the `runtimes.txt` file? Also, I would like this `runtimes.txt` file to be the fourth argument to this Bash file.

Comment: You don't need `eval` here. `output=$( "$1" --seed ...)` is sufficient if `$1` really is just a path name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not particularly elegant but one option would be to use something like this:

```
line=1
for instance in "$2"/*
do
    runtime=$(sed -n "${line}p" "$4")
    line=$(( line + 1 ))
    # etc.
done
```

The counter is incremented in the loop and sed is used to print a single line using the `p` command.

By the way, I think you can (and should!) drop the use of `eval` in your script - I can't see it doing anything useful.

Comment: Or even `(( line++ ))`.

Comment: @fedorqui yeah, that works in bash but `++` isn't required by the POSIX spec so the way I wrote it is more portable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to read several files :

```
while true
do
  read -r val1 <&3 || break
  read -r val2 <&4 || break
  # do whatever you want with the values
done 3<file1 4<file2
```

Comment: So in my case, `file1` and `file2` should be the arguments to the Bash file, i.e. `$2` and `$4`? Like so: `3<$2 4<$4`?

Comment: @JNevens if you're trying to read two files, then that's what you'd do. I was under the impression that you were actually trying to read one line of a file for every path that your glob expands to. I don't think that this approach is suitable for doing that.

Comment: Yes I am iterating over both each file in a folder ($2 is the folder) and each line in a file ($4 will be the file).

Comment: @JNevens Your title is misleading, you don't want to loop over 2 files. I think Tom Fenech's answer is what you need